# A class games.cards.Poker is correctly defined in the jar file Poker.jar. A user wants to execute the main method of Poker on a UNIX system

Tags: java, scjp

**I need help understanding this problem**

The correct answer is 'C'

A class games.cards.Poker is correctly defined in the jar file Poker.jar.
A user wants to execute the main method of Poker on a UNIX system using the command:
java games.cards.Poker
What allows the user to do this?

A. put Poker.jar in directory /stuff/java, and set the CLASSPATH to include /stuff/java

B. put Poker.jar in directory /stuff/java, and set the CLASSPATH to include /stuff/java/*.jar

C. put Poker.jar in directory /stuff/java, and set the CLASSPATH to include /stuff/java/Poker.jar

D. put Poker.jar in directory /stuff/java/games/cards, and set the CLASSPATH to include /stuff/java

E. put Poker.jar in directory /stuff/java/games/cards, and set the CLASSPATH to include /stuff/java/*.jar

F. put Poker.jar in directory /stuff/java/games/cards, and set the CLASSPATH to include /stuff/java/Poker.
jar

Comment: That's how you'd do it anywhere.  (Though you should be able to just have /stuff/java/ in the classpath, I think.)

Comment: I do not think the answer is platform related

Comment: in java but there is no include keyword is there right..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command means, inside the Poker.jar there are directories for games/cards/Poker.java... Don't confuse this with the paths needed to include the jar itself.

```
java games.cards.Poker
```

---

`A. put Poker.jar in directory /stuff/java, and set the CLASSPATH to include /stuff/java`

does not work because setting the classpath as /stuff/java sets the path to your directories/files but it will not go a step further to include your jar (and the classes inside it).

---

`B. put Poker.jar in directory /stuff/java, and set the CLASSPATH to include /stuff/java/*.jar`

does not work because it is not the correct syntax for including all the jar files in one directory. *(Java 6 and higher)* It should be `/stuff/java/*`

---

`D. put Poker.jar in directory /stuff/java/games/cards, and set the CLASSPATH to include /stuff/java`

same as A, including a higher level path does not include all the paths inside of it.

---

`E. put Poker.jar in directory /stuff/java/games/cards, and set the CLASSPATH to include /stuff/java/*.jar`

same as B and A, incorrect syntax + won't include all the paths

---

`F. put Poker.jar in directory /stuff/java/games/cards, and set the CLASSPATH to include /stuff/java/Poker.jar`

classpath here is pointing to the wrong directory for the jar

---

`C. put Poker.jar in directory /stuff/java, and set the CLASSPATH to include /stuff/java/Poker.jar`

This is finally finding the jar, which is in the correct directory.

---

Resources

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)